# Modify all recycler view items show all view holder stacked values

Tags: android-recyclerview

I desire to update each item of a recycled view every second with a new value. But instead of viewing only all updated values, all viewHolders seems to be stacked.

My recyclerView is declared like this :

```
recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycle);
adapter = new ExampleAdapter();
LinearLayoutManager recyclerViewLayout = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(recyclerViewLayout);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

I update the list of the adapter like this :

```
ArrayList<Integer> newList = new ArrayList<Integer>(Arrays.asList(0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9));
private void addNewInt() {
    for (int i=0;i<newList.size();i++) {
        newList.set(i, newList.get(i) + 10);
    }
    adapter.updateList(newList);
}
```

And this is my Adapter :

```
public class ExampleAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder> {    
        private ArrayList<Integer> list;
    
        public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            public TextView txt;
    
            public ViewHolder(View view) {
                super(view);
                txt   = view.findViewById(R.id.txt);
            }
        }

        public ExampleAdapter() {
            this.list = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        public ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            Context context = parent.getContext();
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View cellView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.raw_example, parent, false);
            return new ViewHolder(cellView);
       }

       @Override
       public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ExampleAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
           if (!list.isEmpty()) {
               Integer val = list.get(position);
               holder.txt.setText(Integer.toString(val));
           }
       }

       @Override
       public int getItemCount() {
           return list.size();
       }

       public void updateList(ArrayList<Integer> newList) {
           list.clear();
           list.addAll(newList);
           notifyDataSetChanged();
       }
}
```

The problem does not seem to be linked with recycling. I tried to add  holder.setIsRecyclable(false) to force recreate a new viewHolder without any effect.

I tried also to play with the recyclerView.getRecycledViewPool().setMaxRecycledViews and recyclerView.setItemViewCacheSize() methods without any success.
I try to use notifyItemRangeChange() instead of using the notifyDataSetChanged(). Nothing better.

I also try to force to clear the recyclerview before adding the new elements like this :

```
list.clear();
notifyDataSetChanged();
list.addAll(newList);
notifyDataSetChanged();
```

The xml of my Activity is the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" >

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recycle"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: I have noticed that this bug appears on the Pixel 3A with an android version 9.0. I tried the same code on a Samsung Galaxy A20E android 10.0 and all is working fine. I will try to update my os on the google phone.

Comment: Before updated the OS, I unplugged and plugged again the usb cable and reload my app. The issue is no more reproducible. I really don't understand what happened.